# How to process request sending from xamarin on .net core web api server

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-core

I try to send request with serialized data to my server using HttpClient

```
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(note);
var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content));
```

here my method in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Note>Create([FromBody]note)
{
    _noteService.Create(note);
    return new Note();//CreatedAtRoute("GetBook", new { id = note.Id.ToString() }, note);
}
```

and i get error **Unsupported MediaType**, i tried to change parameter "note" datatype to **StringContent** and i get "**Bad Gateway**" error, i tried to change it to **String** data type and it is empty.

How i can get data sending from xamarin application on my server ?

Edited:
Probably i have to get serialized string and deserialize it to my object.

Comment: Are you not passing note to `Create([FromBody]note)` method as `JSON`?

Comment: Please try with `var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, content);` and let me know the result.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I tried your suggestion and I got error "connot convert string to HttpContent", so it has been fixed by "var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent (content, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json";

Comment: @TanvirArjel thank you

Comment: Oh! got it. Welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, please check solution below

*Xamarin Code*:

```
 var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(note);
 var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

*.Net Core WebApi Code*:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult<Note>Create(Note note)
 {
    _noteService.Create(note);
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetNote", new { id = note.Id.ToString() }, note);
 }
```